# XmlNode.AppendChild, does it literally append?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, append

When using `XmlNode.AppendChild` method, does it literally append to an existing file or does it write a whole new (appended) file?

Microsoft is [quite unclear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx) with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by @Alexei, `AppendChild` only append XML tree loaded in memory.

But in case you are asking about `XmlDocument.Save()` method, that will rewrite the complete XML tree in memory to the output stream.

This can be verified with this piece of code -

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\Sample.xml", 
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
{
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     xmlDoc.Load(fs);

     // Do same changes, like AppendChild on root element

     xmlDoc.Save(fs);
}
```

When you load the file again, you will see the complete XML tree (updated one) is `re-written` below the original XML tree.

Answer (score 2):

`XmlNode.AppendChild` does not append or modify any files. It modifies Xml tree loaded in memory.

If you want to modify file you'd need to save result (as described in the article).

Comment: I wasn't completely clear with the question. What I meant is, once `.Save()` is called, will it append or rewrite whole file?